# How to create option for your app in another app in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

whenever my app will run, it will create one option in another app to get data from another app.
Well, I am not sure this is possible or not, Please guide
one more I know how to share data in between two app by using sent action but I want to create one separate option in another app for my app when my app start running in android 
Is it possible ?

Please guide , Thanks in advance

Comment: is both the apps your, or one is 3ed party?

Comment: Another app is 3rd Party ....D

Answer (score 0):

A content provider component supplies data from one application to others on request. Such requests are handled by the methods of the ContentResolver class. A content provider can use different ways to store its data and the data can be stored in a database, in files, or even over a network.

[Link1](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/contentprovider/android-content-provider-example/)

[Link2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing this way :

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setPackage(TARGET_APP's package name);
context.startActivity(i);
```

You can set value this way with this intent

```
i.putExtra("KEy",value)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double[]%29
```

On the other hand, if you want to read some data from an app, it's possible if and only if that app allows you to do so. Data generated by the app is private by default.

Another way to do this by using content provider

May be this link will help you more about content provider

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm